# If a transmitter wants to send 4k of data and the serial port receives 32 byte of data at a time how to save these bytes in the same memory stream?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with displaying an image it's bytes comes to my pc serial port as chunks of data, 32 bytes at a time, how to keep all the incoming bytes in the same memory stream, then how can I display this image in a picture box

Here is a piece of code

```
if (((int)header[0] == 0x76) && (header[1] == 0x00) && (header[2] == 0x32) && (header[3] == 0x00) && (header[4] == 0x00)) /// the header is true ,read the image bytes
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        Jpg[i] = (byte)CamPort.ReadByte();

    fs.Write(Jpg, 0, Jpg.Length);

    for (int i = 1; i < Jpg.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((Jpg[i - 1] == 0xFF) && (Jpg[i - 0] == 0xD9))// reaching the last two bytes(FF D9) of Jpg //
        {
            EndFlag = true;
            MessageBox.Show("done");
            //OneSnap.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("DONE");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a nested loop and add 32 bytes at a time to a larger array.

```
int offset = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++){
        offset = i * 32;
        jpg[offset + j] = (byte)CamPort.ReadByte();
    }
 }
```

Something like that should get all your data into one array, then you can do manipulation with/on that data. From there it should be a relatively straight-forward matter to display the data in whichever fashion you'd like.

Comment: unfortunately my camera doesn't work now I don't know why >> are you sure that the result will be true :( ?!

Comment: No problem - I had a very similar issue a while back :)

Comment: I have another question hope to help me ...
how can I add progressbar to my form to show the progress of Takingpicture method ??

Comment: The mods will probably get upset you didn't post that in a new question, but basically you can add a progress bar from the toolbox. Every time the loop executes (you can choose whether you want to use the inner or outer loop) you can do progressBar1.PerformStep(). That will increase the bar by whatever step size you specified in the objects properties. Make sure you set the progress bar's maximum value to what you need it to be.